# How to sum the top N values with an OR condition?

Tags: excel

I've been using the following formula to sum the top 3 values on a given column with some criteria. `color` and `values` are named ranges.

`=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((color="red")*(values),{1,2,3}))`

What I couldn't find an answer for is when I want to sum values when color is `red` OR `green`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(((color="red")+(color="green"))*(values),{1,2,3}))
```